# Canvas animation as div background - EaselJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, easeljs

First, I'm sorry for my bad english ^^

I'm working on my web site and I would like to put my canvas animation (created with easelJS framework) in my div background.

I tried something like this :

```
.canvas-bg {
    background: -webkit-canvas(animation);
 }

var ctx = document.getCSSCanvasContext('2d', 'animation', 300, 300);
```

It work on safari (but the animation is paused when I refresh the page) and not working at all on chrome...

So, have you any way to make an animated canvas as div background ?
Like the blue banner of this web site for example : http://www.createjs.com/easeljs

Thanks a lot !
Julien.

Comment: `-webkit-canvas` and `getCSSCanvasContext` are non-standard features and have been removed from everything except for Safari. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, thanks. 
Another solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the canvas in your DIV, and then set it's position as absolute. Other content in the DIV will sit on top.

```
#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
}
```

Here is a quick sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/obcv1rex/1/

You can add text to the first DIV to see it scroll. I set the size to 1000x1000, but to make it more dynamic you would want to size the canvas with JavaScript (using CSS will scale the contents).

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!!! :D
I've already tried that but without the magic line
"overflow: hidden;"